# How to calculate where to add `<tr> and </tr>` when formatting JSON Data as an HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So what I want to do I'm sure has been done thousands of times. I am just having trouble finding the solution.

I am receiving some JSON data that looks like this

```
{
  "ImageCollection": {
    "Images": [{
        "ImageID": "68",
        "CatID": "1",
        "Location": "/Images/Art/Full/68.gif",
        "ClipLocation": "/Images/Art/Clips/68.gif",
        "FullHeight": "504",
        "FullWidth": "451"
      },
      {
        "ImageID": "69",
        "CatID": "1",
        "Location": "/Images/Art/Full/69.gif",
        "ClipLocation": "/Images/Art/Clips/69.gif",
        "FullHeight": "364",
        "FullWidth": "500"
      },
      etc.etc
    ]
  }
}
```

and I want to display the images in a table that is 4 columns wide.
I have the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("/Service/GetJson.ashx?data=images", function(data) {
      var jsObjectData = data.ImageCollection.Images;
      var imageTable = "<table><tbody>";
      var rowMarker = 1;
      var targetRowEnd;
      $.each(jsObjectData, function(i, item) {
          if (
            imageTable = imageTable + "<td class='artImageBox'>"; imageTable = imageTable + "<a title='Click To Add' class='artImage'>"; imageTable = imageTable + "<img id='ArtImg"; imageTable = imageTable + item.ImageID; imageTable = imageTable + "' src='../"; imageTable = imageTable + item.ClipLocation; imageTable = imageTable + "' alt='Click To Add' />"; imageTable = imageTable + "</a></td>";
          }); imageTable = imageTable + "</tbody></table>"; alert(imageTable); $("body").append(imageTable);
      });
</script>
```

But I have not had any luck in calculating where to place the the `<tr> and the </tr>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a running total and break using modulo 4 (totalImages % 4 == 0).

That should do it.

i.e.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("/Service/GetJson.ashx?data=images", function(data) {
    var jsObjectData = data.ImageCollection.Images;
    var imageTable = "<table><tbody>";
    var rowMarker = 1;
    // Initialise our counter
    var imageCount = 0;
    var targetRowEnd;
    $.each(jsObjectData, function(i, item) {
        // Is the count exactly divisble by 4, i.e. start of a new row
        if (imageCount % 4 == 0) {
            imageTable = imageTable + "<tr>";
        }
        imageTable = imageTable + "<td class='artImageBox'>";
        imageTable = imageTable + "<a title='Click To Add' class='artImage'>";
        imageTable = imageTable + "<img id='ArtImg";
        imageTable = imageTable + item.ImageID;
        imageTable = imageTable + "' src='../";
        imageTable = imageTable + item.ClipLocation;
        imageTable = imageTable + "' alt='Click To Add' />";
        imageTable = imageTable + "</a></td>";
        // Count the image we've just inserted
        imageCount++;
        // If the count is again divisible exactly by 4 then it's the end of a row
        // and will be the start of a new row on the next loop.
        if (imageCount % 4 == 0) {
            imageTable = imageTable + "</tr>";
        }
    });
    // Just in case there are not exactly 4 images in the last row lets
    // add a row terminator for the final row if it hasn't met the condition above
    if (imageCount % 4 != 0) {
        imageTable = imageTable + "</tr>";
    }
    imageTable = imageTable + "</tbody></table>";
    alert(imageTable);
    $("body").append(imageTable);
});
</script>
```